# What is the difference between a free Abelian group (of say a finite basis) and a finitely generated Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Is the difference that the generating set of the finitely generating Abelian group need not be linearly independent? I understand that both the basis and the finite generating set span the Abelian group. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Every finite Abelian group is finitely generated, but unless it has order $1$, it is not free Abelian.

Comment: I see, that is a good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every group $G$ is the quotient of a free group $F$. To say that $G$ is finitely generated means that $F$ has a finite set of generators. Saying *basis* and *linearly independent* is the right idea, but isn't quite proper, since we reserve those words for vector spaces. A finitely generated group has a finite *generating set* and possibly some *relations* among those generators.

---

To address your comment and expand a bit, every group $G$ has a *presentation* as a set of generators and relations. For example, this abelian group:
$$G = \left\langle a, b \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}, a^3, b^7 \right\rangle$$ 
Now this group *presentation* is really shorthand for $G$ being the quotient of the free group $\langle a,b\rangle$ by the normal subgroup generated by the elements $\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1}, a^3, b^7 \rangle$. If you want to get fancy and use more categorical language, that presentation of $G$ will be the cokernel of the map $\langle x,y,z \rangle \to \langle a, b \rangle$, such that $x \mapsto aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, $y \mapsto a^3$, and  $z \mapsto b^7$.

Comment: May I please know what you mean by $G$ is the quotient of a group $F$? Quotient of which two groups is $G$? I know that any finitely generated abelian group can be written as the product of a torsion  group and a free abelian group. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I personally find the following perspective useful. This also generalizes nicely to other situations.

An abelian group $G$ is free whenever there is an isomorphism 
$$
\alpha\colon\mathbf{Z}^I \to G
$$
for some index set $I$.
The usual generators of $\mathbf{Z}^I$ are then mapped to generators of $G$ by $\alpha$.

An abelian group $H$ is finitely generated whenever there is a surjective homomorphism
$$
\beta\colon\mathbf{Z}^n \to H. 
$$
for some natural number $n\in\mathbf{N}$. 
Again, $\beta$ maps generators to generators, but now they may be subject to relations. In other words, there is some subgroup $R$ of $\mathbf{Z}^n$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z} ^n / R$.

In the situations above, if $I$ happens to be a finite set, or if $\beta$ happens to be injective (or equivalently, $R=0$), then $G$ or $H$ respectively are both free and finitely generated.

Comment: What is $Z^I$? If we let $I = \{1,...,n\}$ would we not get the same thing as a finitely generated group?